# How do the hanafis explain praying 10 raka't of optional prayers after jumu'ah?

Tags: salat, hanafi, jumuah

A few years ago I've been asked to lead the jumu'ah prayer in a Turkish mosque here in Germany.

So I've asked a hanafi brother to give me some guide lines, as as an Imam I should know the typical procedure how a jumu'ah prayer is held in a hanafi mosque.

One of the things that I learnt was: that after the first adhan they pray one set of optional prayers of 4 raka'a (I assume this is the sunnah before dhor, but I'd be glad to know it better). An other thing is that they pray after the jumu'ah 10 raka'at in 3 sets: 4 raka'a, 4 rak'a and then 2 raka'a.

Now the known sunnah after jumua'h is either praying [4 raka'a](https://sunnah.com/muslim/7/86) at the mosque or practiced two at the mosque and two at home (which might be based on an other narration saying that the Prophet() prayed only two) or praying two according [the hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/11/61). This is the practice within other madhabs.

After doing some research I found that the hanafi brothers at least have some narrations which may explain praying 6 raka'at after jumu'ah (as a combination of both ahadith from above for example). But this still doesn't explain why they pray 10 raka'a. I'd like to have an explanation about that,as maybe I miss something?

Comment: (Wait, you're an imam?!  I feel like I should know this already.)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones at the time I was a student at university and some of us have been leading the jumu'ah prayer for our (Muslim Student) community. I could say we were not the best ones for this job, but the the ones who were willing to take the responsibility.

Comment: My mosque is Hanafi so what they do is say the first Adhan and then pray 4 raka'a sunnah, then say the 2nd adhan and then the Khutba  and then the 2 raka'a fard and then 4 raka'a sunnah and then 2 raka'a Sunnah but some people don't pray the 2 raka'a Sunnah or pray it at home and then there is 2 raka'a nafl.

Comment: @Armaan well this is the practice at Turkish mosques, my friend whom I consulted is a Syrian, so I assumed this is the general practice at hanafi mosques.

Comment: @Uma that was indeed my assumption, they seem to offer 4 extra raka'as for dhor before and after, beside the 4+2 for Jumu'ah.

Comment: @Uma ups the for fard is something i would assume the practice of shafi'is as I know a brother whom used always to pray dhor after jumu'a as he states that the minimum amount for the congregation was not present when the imam starts the khotba. AFAIK the hanfis only require 3 people for jumu'ah to be established. I was thinking of sunnah raka'a not fard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59866/discussion-between-medi1saif-and-uma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rakahs of Friday Prayer according to the Hanafis are as follows:

4 Sunnah <sup>1</sup>
2 Fard (with congregation)
4 آخر ظهر  (Akhir Zuhr) <sup>2</sup>
4 Sunnah
2 Sunnah
2 Nafal

---

<sup>1</sup> These are based on narrations to that effect. Some are listed [here](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/16609). The following are to the credit to [III-AK-III](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/8393/iii-ak-iii):

From [al-Ghaya 1/214](http://sh.bib-alex.net/olomhadith/Web/5956/001.htm)

> الصَّلَاة قبل الْجُمُعَة أَربع
>
> The prayer before Jummah are four (rakahs).

From [al-Diraya 1/217](http://ablibrary.net/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C/%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%A7/8600_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%AA%D8%AE%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%AC%20%D8%A3%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9(1)/%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%87_217)

> عن ابن عباس كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يركع قبل الجمعة أربعا لا
> يفصل في
> شيء منهن
>
> Ibn Abbas related that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) offered four rakahs before Jummah and did not separate them [in twos?].

---

<sup>2</sup> From what I understand, these are offered as a precautionary measure when the validity of the congregation of Jumah is doubted. These make up for the 4 *fard* Rakahs of Zuhr which should have been offered if Jumah was truly invalid and hence missed. The reasons for the Jumah being invalid can range from the impressibility within the schools of two separate congregations within a single city, or the legal incapacity of the Imam to lead the congregation etc.(See [Hidayah](https://archive.org/stream/Hedaya_201703/Hedaya#page/n131/mode/2up)).

[Ibn Abidin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Abidin) (Shami) of the Hanafi school [discusses this in Dar ul Mukhtar](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=27&ID=1177):

> قلت : وحاصله أنه يصلي بعد الجمعة عشر ركعات أربعا سنتها وأربعا آخر ظهر
> وركعتين سنة الوقت : أي لاحتمال أن الفرض هو الظهر فتقع الركعتان سنته
> البعدية . والظاهر أنه يكفي نية آخر ظهر عن الأربع سنة الجمعة إذا صحت
> الجمعة لأن المعتمد عدم اشتراط التعيين في السنن ، وإن لم تصح فالفرض هو
> الظهر وتقع الأربع التي صلاها قبل الجمعة عن سنة الظهر القبلية لكن لطول
> الفصل بصلاة الجمعة وسماع الخطبة يصلي أربعا أخرى فالأولى صلاة العشرة

Also see [islamqa.org/hanafi](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/34764):

> Regarding the 4 extra rak'ah of “zuhr akhir” : there is no need for
> this, unless there is a reasonable doubt that one or more of the
> conditions (shurut) of Jumu'ah were not fulfilled. If that is the
> case, then the order you mention (4 sunnah 2 fard 4 sunnah 4 zuhr
> akhir 2 sunnah) is fine. [Ibn 'Abidin]

And on [fazilettakvimi.com](http://www.fazilettakvimi.com/en/2017/4/30.html):

> According to the Ijtihad view that Salat Juma’ can only be prayed in
> one Masjid, whichever Masjid starts the prayer first, their Salat will
> be accepted and all others that start later will not be accepted.  To
> escape from such a disagreement, it is advised to pray a further four
> Rak’ah, called Zuhr-i Akhir after the second four Rak’ah Sunnah of
> Salat Juma’.
>
> The intentions is: Zuhr-i Akhir is prayed like the four Rak’ah Fard or
> four Rak’ah Sunnah of Zuhr.  The best way is to pray is like the
> Sunnah.  Because if the Salat Juma’ is not fulfilled, then this will
> act as a cover to fulfil it.  Adding a Surah or some Ayahs after Surah
> Fatiha to the last two Rak’ah’s does not affect it.  And if Salat
> Juma’ has been fulfilled, then this will be in place of a Salat Zuhr
> which has not be prayed before (Qaza).  If there is no Qaza Salat like
> this, then this will be counted as Nawafil Salat.

Comment: *"The reasons for the Jumah being invalid can range from the impressibility within the schools of two separate congregations within a single city"* would this mean if only one juma'ah was held in a city the 4 raka'a wouldn't be necessary? I know that classical books say that the jumua'ah should be prayed in one (single) mosque in a city...

Comment: The hadith from al-Dirayah seems to support the hanafi view in praying sets of 4 raka'a at least before jumu'ah in this case.

Comment: @Medi1Saif If all the conditions for the Jummah are fulfilled then yes. Though this is based on 'reasoning' and not sunnah per se.

Answer (score -1):

4 raka,a sunnah after first adan for jummah
2 raka,a fard with imam
4 raka,a sunnah 
2 raka,a sunnah 
2 raka,a nafal

Comment: I clearly wrote 10 raka'a after the jumuah prayer! What you've quoted are 8 raka'as and this lacks explanation. I don't see how this answers or addresses my question fully.