# Is wearing a nosepin allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, islamic-basis

I want to know that can a woman/girl in Islam wear a nosepin if her intention with it is not bad like attracting opposite gender or anything?

Comment: I guess it is ok especially if it is a local custom.

Comment: @Medi1Saif can you please answer in the light of the Qur'an or hadith?

Answer (score 1):

The Prophet (pbuh) said:

> “What is halaal is that which God has permitted in His Book, and what
>   is haraam is that which God has forbidden in His Book, and what He has
>   remained silent about is forgivable.” Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 1726;
>   classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.

While there are hadiths which prohibits women from removing hair from face or making spaces among their teeth but there are no verses or authentic hadiths which prohibits women from wearing jewellery.

Therefore, It is not forbidden.