# Are 4 Fard rakats mandatory in Friday Jummah prayer?

Tags: hanafi, jumuah

I know that there are total 12 rakats in Zohar prayer. For the friday prayer along with imam in a jamat there is bayan then khudbah then 2 Fard rakats.

I would like to know along with these 2 rakats offered with imam how many else additional fard rakats are there ?

I know there are 4 sunnah, 4 Fard, 2 Sunnah and 2 Nifil.

If we read 2 Fard with Imam , are the 4 fard mandatory ?

Comment: There are only 2 Fard rakahs in Jumu’ah. This is well known and you should be able to find this on your own by a simple search.

Comment: @UmH So the left are 4 Sunnah,2 Sunnah and 2 nafal right ?

Comment: You seem to refer to hanafi madhhab. Since jumu'ah has no defined Sunnah before the prayer, but only 2 or 4 after the prayer depending on whether or not you pray at home or in the mosque.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Jumu'ah rakats aren't the same as that of the Zohar prayer ? So do you mean that there is no other rakat before or after the 2 Fard rakat by the imam ?

Comment: I mean the topic I've requested in [How do the hanafis explain praying 10 raka't of optional prayers after jumu'ah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40360/how-do-the-hanafis-explain-praying-10-rakat-of-optional-prayers-after-jumuah#40378)